# Field isn't validated in right way in CakePHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I was trying to set up form validation inside CakePHP. Model is recognized when entering submit form, but i have few problems:

1. When i enter any validation rule, the only thing that is checked is whenever in field is any text.
2. I can't do multiple rules per field - they are not working.
3. I can still type in artist field values, that are not alphanumeric...

Here is my Model code:

```
class Sounds extends AppModel {

public $validate = array(   
    'artist' => array(          
        'rule1' => array(
        'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please enter value',
        'last'    => false
        ),
        'rule2' => array(
        'rule'    => 'alphaNumeric',
        'message' => 'Please enter alphanumeric value'
        )           
    )

);
```

Also in SoundController i have code, to check if form was validated:

```
if ($this->Sounds->validates()) { //action if validated } else {
$errors = $this->Sounds->validationErrors;
$this->set('errors_submit',$errors);
```

Comment: By convention model names are supposed to be singular in Cakephp. So your model class name should be `Sound` and filename should be `Sound.php`

Comment: And controller should be plural: SoundsController, not singular like you have.

Comment: So i've changed values - SoundsController.php, Sound.php (in Model) - and now validation doesn't work at all...

Comment: Are you setting values before you call `validates()` using `$this->Sound->set($this->request->data);`?

Comment: Thanks You marian0! You've just resolved my problem :)!